# Angular.js ng-repeat array shows as json

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays, json

I have an issue where I'm trying to display an array in Angularjs using ng-repeat but its showing the entire json array and not only the text inside.

This is my array

```
$scope.problems = [

    {
        problem: "problem1",
        works: [
            "a0",
            "a9"
        ]
    }
]
```

And this is where I want to display it

```
<li ng-repeat="works in problems | filter: searchCard">{{works}}</li>
```

Now the `{{works}}` tag shows this in the live document:

```
{"problem":"probleem1","works":["a0","a9"]}
```

According to most tutorials and things i've seen its supposed to display the a0 and a9 not the entire json line.

My second question which might be completely different is, how can I display the text correctly but also hide all of them until a person has used the input to search the "works" input field.

Comment: For a second question, you should open a new thread, with only the code needed to solve that second issue

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe I will in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the nested ng-repeats like @Maher mentioned. also, in order to hide data until `searchCard` is typed, you can use `ng-if` directive in nested `ui`.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in problems | filter: searchCard">
  {{item.problem}}
  <ul ng-if="searchCard">
    <li ng-repeat="work in item.works">{{work}}</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I don't get why you added the `ng-if`

Comment: as for my understanding OP says `how can i display the text correctly but also hide all of them until a person has used the input to search the "works" input field`

Answer (score 3):

when you have **objects Array** on ng-repeat you have to select that object params; in this sample our object params are **"problem"** and **"works"**

also in our object we have **"string array"** and string array not have params because that we use it **directly** in this sample `{{work}}` is object of string array.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in problems | filter: {problem: searchCard}">
  {{item.problem}}
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="work in item.works">{{work}}</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks man it works like intended, quick follow up question if I can, can I hide the list untill someone uses the filter: searchCard I want the array to be hidden untill a user searches for example A1 and it'll show A1 in the text? I'm thinking it might need an ng-if but I have no clue how.

Comment: you have to Specified param you are searching

Comment: I couldnt edit my comment anymore but the user below this post has answered my search question, thanks to both of you!

Comment: you have to Specified param you are searching, for example you want search about `problem` , use this `filter: {problem: searchCard}`